# How to Backup Jenkins using Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

How To do Jenkins jobs configuration backup using Jenkinsfile without plugins?

things to be backup :

1. system configuration {jenkins}
2. jobs configuration

Comment: How about some more details? What do you wan to back up? The basic system configuration, the entire system configuration, all the job configurations, the job configurations and the build histories (logs) and the workspaces ? If you don't have the plugis configurations, you'll never know what you need if you re-add a job unless you go analyze it..

Comment: things to be backup 1. system configuration {jenkins}. 2. jobs configuration.

Comment: I think Jenkinsfile is the wrong way to achieve this. You should do this on a system level directly e.g via cron. Anyway you could run a job on master copying all the $JENKINS_HOME folder to some nfs storage or any other storage.

Comment: A single Jenkinsfile should not have an access to Jenkins server configuration files. If you allow that, you open a huge security hole - anyone who can create a job/pipeline could access anything from the Jenkins folder.

Comment: in a default config, ${JENKINS_HOME} is too much. You get exploded war, exploded jar, caches, build logs workspaces, everything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We were not happy with the plugins backup solutions, so we have a freestyle shell step job run on master (usually a no-no, so only allow managed special task like backup to run there) with a simple tar cmd, one for system config (xmls, keys, etc), one for jobs (excluding logs 'n stuff).

---

## System backup

In `${JENKINS_HOME}`, you'll want to backup:

```
# Jenkins launcher
jenkins
jenkins.conf
#Jenkins install states
jenkins.install.*
# secrets
secret.key*
identity.key.enc
init.groovy   # if you have one
# ALL the configuration files
*.xml   # This covers the config.xml and all the plugins xmls
#
# directories:
secrets
init.groovy.d   # if you have one
nodes
users
userContent  # if you have content there
```

## Plugins

I don't believe there is a need to store `caches, updates, plugins,` etc.

We manage plugins separately so we simply store the versioned list of plugins used - see this [DevOps post for the groovy](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/9749/13379) and reinstall from the list if necessary. If you choose, backup plugins and updates separately from the rest but together.

---

## Jobs backup

We don't really care about the builds logs, but we do care about the configuration (`config.xml`) and next build number (`nextBuildNumber`). We use the following 2-step tar to build the list; this allows us to traverse Jenkins folders of arbitrary depth without reading the entire directory tree, skipping `builds` and `htmlreports`, etc.

```
find ${JENKINS_HOME}/jobs/*/* -type d \( -name builds -o -name htmlreports \) -fprint /dev/null -prune \
   -o -type f  \( -name config.xml -o -name nextBuildNumber \) -print > jenkins-jobs.lst
tar -czf Jenkins.jobs.${label}.tgz -C ${JENKINS_HOME} --no-recursion --files-from=jenkins-jobs.lst
```

Comment: I am going to try it.

Comment: @maheshs007, any feedback?