# Backing up Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, devops, continuous-delivery

What is the optimal way to create a backup of your **Jenkins** CI server?

Currently, we create snapshots of the VM where **Jenkins** server is running but is there a more Agile/DevOps-y way of doing this?

Comment: What are you trying to preserve by backing up? Jenkins coonfiguration, all the jobs configuration, all the jobs logs, all the workspaces as well? Lots of answers here on tbe first two, which are important, the rest, who cares?

Comment: The server configuration and jobs config.Those are the most crucial to get up and running again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my [prior response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58875687/598141) to a similar question.  I'd also really advocate managing your configuration using [Configuration as Code](https://plugins.jenkins.io/configuration-as-code/) plugin, which is well supported now and manage system that way.

ps:It helps to search S/O before asking similar questions.